# Laravel form model binding for many to many select input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a many to many relationship between `clients` and `assets`.
For my edit client form I have multi-select box with which the user can select several `assets` to attach to a client. The form is using model-binding so it automatically populates the fields with the existing client data.

The model binding works for all fields in the form except the multi-select. Here is a snippet from my view:

```
{{ Form::model($client, ['route' => ['clients.update', $client->id], 'class' => '', 'method' => 'put']) }}

{{ Form::label('name', 'Name', $label_attributes) }}
{{ Form::text('name', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) }}

{{ Form::label('assets', 'Client Benchmarks (Select multiple)', $label_attributes) }}
{{ Form::select('assets[]', $assets, null, array('multiple' => true, 'class' => 'form-control')); }}
```

When I submit the form the relationship saves the data successfully via the `sync` method in my controller (`update` method):

```
$client = Client::find($id);
$client->name = Input::get('name');    
$assets = Input::has('assets') ? Input::get('assets') : array();
$client->assets()->sync($assets);
$client->save();
```

Also, if I output the client assets directly they are accessible in the model collection in my form view:

```
<?php print_r($client->assets); ?>
```

How can I get the form to populate the select box with the existing selections?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo Form::select('assets[]', $assets, array(1,2), array('multiple' => true));
```

As far as I know it won't set all selected values by default for you even when using form 
model binding

This is what the native formBuilder method looks like:

```
public function select($name, $list = array(), $selected = null, $options = array())
```

Comment: Yeah, that is not ideal as it would be nice to be able to use the model binding on all fields in the form. Look like I need to manually pass the selected values to the `select()` method.

Comment: Afraid so, I agree that it doesn't make a lot of sense but it wouldn't be difficult to pass in an array of currently 'active' values

Comment: Indeed, although I need to do something like `array_pluck($client->assets->toArray(), 'id')` which isn't exactly the most elegant thing.

Comment: You could use laravel's 'lists' instead :) (or php's array_column)